# Getting value in javascript from Out Of The Box CQ5 Form text component

Tags: javascript, aem

How do I get a value from Out Of The Box CQ5 Form Text component to javascript?

I tried by using this code but its not fetching the value.

```
var x=document.getElementsByName("propertyname");
```

propertyname : is the name property set for the CQ5 Form Text component.

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByName returns an HTMLCollection (since there can be more than one field with the same name in an html page), hence you would need to iterate over it to get every element and then get the corresponding value.

```
window.onload = init(); 

function init() {
    var properties = document.getElementsByName("propertyname");
    for(var i=0; i<properties.length; i++) {
        //properties[i].value gives the value of the field.
        alert(properties[i].value);
    }
};
```